# Alternatives to bloom for glow?

Tags: android, shaders, textures, unreal, bloom

I am making an android game. Mobile phones are usually very limited in graphics capability and so I do not want to use standard post-process bloom due to performance drawbacks.

However I do want to have some objects in the game to appear glowing e.g. explosions, jewels etc, nothing very fancy just like it used to be on older hardware such as N64 and PS1.

[image]

What method and practices are common to get the desired look?

Comment: It's just a sprite that multiplies with the color behind it.

Comment: @Sidar usually this is done with additive blending rather than multiplicative.

Comment: true. multiplying by white is not changing the color.